# Cant do full row editing when double clicking back to same row

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, fullrowselect

Let say we have row a in a table, first time full row editing works after double clicking on the row. But when double clicking outside the row, and clicking back the same row, full row editing not working. The second time full row editing only works if input different values when it works first time or refresh the page.

Expectation is full row editing should work every time re-double clicking on the row.

I tried to enable and disable `stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus`, issue still there.